# mongoose $literal in find method projection

Tags: database, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose find method like this,

```
photo.find({},{
name:1,
src:1,
likes:{$literal:[]},
dislikes:{$literal:[]},
}).then(photos => ....)
```

what I want is, when I run the code  likes and dislikes field must be an empty array for every record.
I try this way but not working.

```
 Unsupported projection option: likes: { $literal: 1 }
```

Any idea to add default value for any field in find method ?

Answer (score 0):

As per mongoose, document schema is constructed during its creation. So you can also edit the schema with a default value, so for every record, when it is created it will create likes, and dislikes with empty values.

You can also do this way, if you feel the schema control is not in your hands.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/defaults.html

```
photo.find({ 'name' : '1', 'likes': {$ne: []}})
```